# Trying to load a 32-bit library on a 64-bit Windows with 32-bit Java: java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror

Tags: java, unsatisfiedlinkerror, windows64

I am getting java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\liblept168.dll:
```

The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail

error on Windows 64-bit platform, with 32-bit Java installed. The .dll that I am trying to load requires 32-bit Java.

I checked liblept168.dll, it is in

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\
```

Also

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\
```

is in the PATH in Environment Variables.

Does anyone have any reccommendation about this issue? Actually I tried this in my locale (which is also a 64-bit Windows with 32-bit Java) and it worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you just check what version of jdk is already available in classpath

Comment: I expect you will find the answer (or at least, more clues) in the event log, like the error message says.

Comment: Is it possible that there are multiple java.exe available on PATH? Could you try using the full path to invoke java?